Equivalence of solutions to PDE in different coordinate systems
Wave equation in two dimensions can be solved either in Cartesian or polar coordinates. One can derive the expressions for Laplacian by putting in the coordinate transformations directly. However, this must also be valid at the solution level. I have never seen a proof that the solutions to wave equation or any other PDE for that matter written in different coordinate systems, say plane polar and 2D Cartesian actually match. This is probably because the algebra in messy, but I want to know how this can be done. For tougher examples, one might have to use identities of special functions appearing in the solution of the PDE, so I gave the example of 2D wave equation which seems to be one of the easiest non-trivial toy examples, to me. But please feel free to show that the solutions to a different PDE, in different coordinate systems match explicitly, using any other example where the math is simpler.
EDIT:
As it is made obvious in the correct answer by Kaikash, the solutions to the PDE should match which was already implicit in my question. I am looking for an explicit matching of solutions in different coordinate systems. In other words, given a solution to a PDE and a coordinate transformation rule, find out the solution to the PDE in the new coordinates without having to solve the PDE again. Solving PDEs are hard: if we found some solution in some coordinates, why would we bother to solve the PDE again if we can simply do a coordinate transformation? Apart from this motivation, one can always cross-check solutions to a PDE in a new coordinate system, by getting the solution in two ways: solving the PDE directly and making a coordinate transformation of the solution from the old system.

Say you have an equation $\Delta u = f$ in one coordinate system. Then in another coordinate system, using $\widetilde{}$ for quantities in the other coordinate system, we have $\widetilde{\Delta u} = \widetilde{f}$. Now the formula for $\widetilde{\Delta}$ is derived precisely so that $\widetilde{\Delta u} = \widetilde{\Delta}\widetilde{u}$, so we get $\widetilde{\Delta}\widetilde{u} = \widetilde{f}$. Of course, we can go in reverse too. Hence the equation $\Delta u = f$ holds if and only if $\widetilde{\Delta}\widetilde{u} = \widetilde{f}$ holds. Note that all the algebra is packed into proving the identity $\widetilde{\Delta u} = \widetilde{\Delta} \widetilde{u}$.

Given $u$ and the coordinate transformation, is it possible to derive $\tilde{u}$ without actually solving the PDE again in the new "$\tilde{}$" coordinate system?

If you are in coordinate system $O_x \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and you have another coordinate system $\Omega_y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with transition map $F : \Omega \to O$, $x = F(y)$, then $\tilde{u}(y) = u(F(y)) = u(x)$ is the definition of $\tilde{u}$. There is nothing to derive here.

Yeah I know that. What I was asking in the question, was an explicit case where this transformation is performed. E.g. You have some spherical harmonics for Laplace equation in spherical polar coordinates, where in rectangular Cartesian coordinates you have exponentials. I wanted to see the calculation that indeed the two solutions are equivalent.

A motivation of why one should want this extremely unelegant looking math: Suppose we have a PDE with known solutions in one coordinates, and by some method I find out solutions to the same PDE in some other coordinates. I could cross-check my calculation by doing the coordinate transformation of my solution.

Yes cross checking can be helpful to check for algebra mistakes. But my point was that the method of changing coordinates gives a solution to the PDE, and that is a mathematical fact. The equations $\Delta u = f$ and $\tilde{\Delta} \tilde{u} = \tilde{f}$ are equivalent, and solving either gives a solution to the other.

I could only ever see there being a nontrivial issue with your procedure if the PDE does not have unique solutions. Otherwise, uniqueness guarantees that any solutions produced by any consistent coordinate change are equivalent
